# Tablib xlsx file badZip file issue

Tags: python, tablib

I am getting error on opening xlsx extension file in windows 8 using tablib library.

python version  - 2.7.14

error is as follows:

```
python suit_simple_sheet_product.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "suit_simple_sheet_product.py", line 19, in <module>
    data = tablib.Dataset().load(open(BASE_PATH).read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tablib\core.py", line 446, in load
    format = detect_format(in_stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tablib\core.py", line 1157, in detect_format
    if fmt.detect(stream):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tablib\formats\_xls.py", line 25, in detect
    xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=stream)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 120, in open_workbook
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(timemachine.BYTES_IO(file_contents))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
zipfile.BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

path location is as follows = 
BASE_PATH = 'C:\Users\anju\Downloads\automate\catalog-5090 fabric detail and price list.xlsx'

Comment: You could try `open(BASE_PATH, 'rb')` to open the xlsx file in binary mode.

Comment: can you please provide me some complete example of tablib. I have tried your tip but somehow the data i am getting after using it, does not give all rows data excepting column names of sheet.

Comment: Your xlsx file might be using features that the underlying `xlrd` library does not support. You could use something like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to upload your file to and paste the URL to it here.

Answer (score 3):

Excel `.xlsx` files are actually zip files. In order for the unzip to work correctly, the file must be opened in binary mode, as such your need to open the file using:

```
import tablib

BASE_PATH = r'c:\my folder\my_test.xlsx'
data = tablib.Dataset().load(open(BASE_PATH, 'rb').read())

print data
```

Add `r` before your string to stop Python from trying to interpret the backslash characters in your path.